# How to access an API which is having high response time in android app?

Tags: java, android, performance

I have a java API that is taking around 50 sec to return the response and improvement in API is not possible. User can not proceed in next page until the response is complete and it is kind of blocker in the android app which is using the API. Please suggest some alternate approach on this.

For example: we can have two table and API will return the data from table instead waiting for the result of query which is taking more time and we can spawn a thread to run the query in the background and update the table data with the result. Based upon time stamp in response data android app can know the data is old or latest and in case of old data they can request it again after some time to get the latest data.

Please let me know if the question or approach is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is specific way of doing such things. There is a thing called `Loader` in android. `CursorLoader` is used for content providers. and `AsyncTaskLoader` for api calls

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
}
```

also add this dependencies in gradle app level

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

Smaple response

```
Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 07:33:23 GMT
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1470987074283
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1470987074422
```

Comment: and also check your logcat in android studio

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in background Service.
And notify UI thread when get response through broadcast.